# jQuery Switch Button On/Off Should Set Different Data-status & Onclick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, toggle

Still learning jQuery and will be thankful for any help.

I am currently using this jQuery Switchbutton https://github.com/olance/jQuery-switchButton
It uses a checkbox as an input type, and creates span tags with labels.
How would I say that I want on_label to have **data-status**="accept", and off_label **data-status**="decline"?

HTML:
`<input type="checkbox"  id="accept-offer"/>`

JS:
`$("input#accept-offer").switchButton({
                on_label: "Accept",
                off_label: "Ignore"

           });`

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you perhaps create a jsfiddle for this, it'll help us help you faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this:

```
$('.switch-button-label.on').data('status','accept');
$('.switch-button-label.off').data('status','decline');
```

or:

```
$('.switch-button-label.on').attr('data-status','accept');
$('.switch-button-label.off').attr('data-status','decline');
```

Comment: Thanks, could you possible show me how to include it within the js?

Comment: @robinyapockets just put this code in in any js files that load after your `switchButton` files. Normally, I'll put it in a file called `script.js` and include this file at the end of page before `</body>` tag. Make sure you put this code in `$(function() { });` to make sure the DOM is ready :)